# Keep getting an error 2 message after importing project related to my JDK

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-13

I'm having the following problem when installing IntelliJ and trying to import a project.

I already installed JDK 7 and JDK 8 and set the JAVA_HOME to point at the right folder:

```
Monkis-MacBook-Pro-2:Home dalvik$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_71.jdk/Contents/Home
```

[image]

Any help would be much appreceiated

Comment: What does "SBT project" mean?

Comment: Its the path to the project that was built using SBT, and so adapted to it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like somewhere in Idea or in your system there is settings which points Java path to your user's home directory - /Users/nativ/bin/java
Which I believe is not the right one and missing.

Check your .bash_profile or any sbt related settings.

Check also jenv project, might be helpful for you. 
https://github.com/gcuisinier/jenv